# TabBar inSide the StackNavigation in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-0.46, stack-navigator

I will take [**StackNavigation**](https://reactnavigation.org/) for Push and Pop with its parameter. Its Working fine. But Now I want to implement after some screen TabBar after StackNavigation, Have any Idea How to Take TabBar after StackNavigation.

Note : I want to implement Custom TabBar.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: You can use TabNavigator from react-navigation package

Comment: But Its Was default TabBar. i want to custom.

Comment: You can customize it according to your requirement.

Comment: provide what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
let StackWithTabs1 = StackNavigator({ // stackNavigator inside the tabNavigator
  Screen3:{
    screen: Screen3
  }
  ,Screen4:{
    screen: Screen4
  }
});

let StackWithTabs2 = StackNavigator({ // stackNavigator inside the tabNavigator
      Screen5:{
        screen: Screen5
      }
      ,Screen6:{
        screen: Screen6
      }
    });

let tab_bar = TabNavigator({
      StackWithTabs1 : {
        screen: StackWithTabs1 // Calling the stackNavigators that going to go inside the tabNavigator
      },
      StackWithTabs2 : {
        screen: StackWithTabs2 
      }
    });

let InitialStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Screen1: {
    screen: Screen1
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2
  },
  tabBar: {
    screen: tab_bar // Calling the tabNavigator, wich contains the other stackNavigators
  }
});
```

Just declare your `tabNavigator` and its `stackNavigators` apart and then call them on the main `stackNavigator`.

Comment: Hi, I want to reload tab on selection. how can i achieve.\

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same problem :/